# RGBA CSS3 Gradients in 16 Bits ?

Tags: css, webkit, gradient

I use CSS3 gradients from some times now, and I notice that from few versions of Webkit and Gecko, when you use RGBA in your colors values, some lines appears on the gradient like it was only 16bit.

A made a JSBin, check this with Chrome : http://jsbin.com/ojadan/4/edit

Is someone find how to solve this problem ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I found this resources. It works for me.

http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Gradient/

As far as how smooth the color gradations are on your screen, you might want to check your graphics accelerator/display settings. Make sure they are set to 16bit or better yet, 32bit. Even 16bit will sometimes show some color grading. This of course may vary from one browser to another. There is very little you can do to address this from within your code.

Good Luck